Azure DataFactory global parameter that concats string with pipeline parameter?
I have a bunch of pipes that use pipeline parameters to complete a SQL command string.
Pipeline Expression Example that works:
@concat(
'UPDATE DW00_SYS.dbo.ADFScheduler
SET 
    PIPE_STARTTIME = GETDATE()
    ,PIPE_ENDTIME = NULL
    ,PIPE_STATUS = ''RUNNING''
WHERE SYS_ABBR =  ''',pipeline().parameters.SYS_ABBR,'''
    AND TABLE_NAME =  ''',pipeline().parameters.TABLE_NAME,'''
    AND PIPE_NAME = ''',pipeline().Pipeline,'''
    AND MULTIDAY_ID = ',pipeline().parameters.MULTIDAY_ID,';

SELECT 0 ID;')

It is quite a chore if I need to modify the command because I have to open up 30-50 pipelines and copy/paste the new expression into each one.
Is there a way that I could write the expression as a global parameter that each pipeline references? I have not been able to get the pipeline to recognize the pipeline parameters as parameters. It just thinks it's a long string.

AFAIK, the global parameters are not supported the dynamic expressions. Those are only constants which can be accessed by any pipeline in ADF.

Is there a reason you could not put this in its own pipeline ("this" -- is this a copy activity?) and then put an execute pipeline activity in the 30-50 pipelines, and make your update to SQL in this one pipeline with the single copy activity? I would suggest this as an answer but I don't want to assume that this is doable, need more context on the purpose of this and where it fits in a workflow

Currently, the pipeline parameters in ADF are constants and doesn't support the dynamic expressions. The same goes with the Global parameter as well. Whatever the dynamic expression that you have provided, it will treat it as a given type only. That is the reason why it is giving a long string.
I do agree with @Chris Umphlett's comment. If the source and target are same in all pipelines, you can have a copy activity with above expression in a pipeline and call this pipeline from your pipelines using Execute pipeline activities where you can pass the required values to those parameters.
You can also try below workaround if your expression only involves the pipeline parameters and variables.
Build the query using string interpolation @{} and give that to the global parameter as shown below sample.
update mytable1 set name='@{pipeline().parameters.new_name}' where id>@{pipeline().parameters.id};SELECT 0 ID;


Now, in the pipeline, replace the strings of the parameters @{pipeline().parameters.<param_name>} with original parameter value like below.
@replace(replace(pipeline().globalParameters.global_exp,'@{pipeline().parameters.new_name}',pipeline().parameters.new_name),'@{pipeline().parameters.id}',pipeline().parameters.id)

Like this way, you need to replace all parameters in your query.

Result query:

